# How to cancel out of an activity that got started with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity `Activity1` that starts `Activity2` with `startActivityForResult(..)`

In `Activity2` I have a save button that calls an AsyncTask and in `onSuccess` I return the activity back and everything works fine.

However, if the user doesn't click the `save` button but instead the back button then I get an error such as this:

```
android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.myapp.mobile/com.myapp.mobile.ui.activity.Activity2} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3467)
```

Below is my sample code:

**in Activity1**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Activity.this,Activity2.class);  
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

.....

@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    if(requestCode==2) {  
        //do some stuff here  
    }  
}
```

**in Activity2**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    if (menuItem.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Save")) {
        new MyAsyncTask(this, intent, someData).execute();
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Question**

How can I fix this? How can I let the user click back (`home`) and not kill my app?

Comment: Have to overridden the onBackPressed() method on the second activity, without calling its super? Also, post more of your stack trace.

Comment: I have not pressed the `onBackPressed()` on second activity. Should I just `finish` the activity in there?

Comment: onBackPresse() by default will take you to the first Activity which is similar to finishing the second one manually. Oh great. you got your answer. Have fun coding. Thanks to @beworker :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks you have overwritten `onDestroy()` method in `Activity2` and didn't call `super.onDestroy()` there.

Comment: great that did the trip. Thanks